# Will this work for a wet vent?

Tags: venting

I am not sure if I properly understand the wet vent concept so here is the question.

The current bathroom apparently has no dry venting. I am moving the sink from the point marked on the wall just behind where it says '2"(to be confirmed)' to the position shown in the picture ("new sink)"
The piping is not much longer in this layout. I can upgrade everything to 2"

Will this comply with a wet venting design ? ( *I am assuming that in the past the wet venting was via the soil stack or it was not there at all and the design is not valid*)

[image]

Some more info
Old layout before demo
[image]
Current situation

[image]

What I want to build

[image]

Comment: What is preventing you form venting up and around in the walls, per usual,  to get to the stack?

Comment: Add link to the other question for continuity.

Comment: Have you considered Air admittance valve under new sink?  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Studor-Mini-Vent-Air-Admittance-Valve-with-PVC-Adapter/1000604287

Comment: I could I do not have an issue with that if it is OK

Comment: @AlaskaMan see the updates -the green segments are not there I was thinking about reusing the plumbing for the sink that I want to move to add some venting to the whole thing but before there was none and the only venting I have is the grey pipe that currently has no role in venting or draining for basement, hence this all ordeal to safely remove it

Comment: Oh it’s a pedestal sink?  An AAV is kind of clunky under a pedestal sink. But you can go up in the wall behind the sink and use a AAV with a recess box and face plate    https://www.lowes.com/pd/Studor-Air-Admittance-Valve-Recess-Box-with-Faceplate/1000679311

Comment: no the new layout includes a full cabinet and a sink...see the updates

Comment: @MiniMe  AAV may be a good solution for you. Some states and local AHJ’s do not approve their usage. If you are concerned  about that check with local AHJ.   Use a high quality one and place it up close to top of cabinet.

Comment: yes at this point I am pretty much sold to that idea, I will play safe and add it. It is allowed in Ontario